# C++ primer 5th edition: dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have this text from C++ Primer 5th edition:

> `dynamic_cast<type*>(e)`
>
> `dynamic_cast<type&>(e)`
>
> `dynamic_cast<type&&>(e)`
>
> In all cases, the type of `e` must be either a class type that is publicly derived from the target type , a `public` base class of the target type , or the same as the target type . If `e` has one of these types, then the cast will succeed. Otherwise, the cast fails. If a `dynamic_cast` to a pointer type fails, the result is 0. If a dynamic_cast to a reference type fails, the operator throws an exception of type bad_cast.

- It is said that "the type of `e` must be either a class type that publicly derived from the target type..." I think the contrary he meant because if the type of `e` is derived from the type cast then we don't need a conversion or cast because they are implicitly convertible by inheritance But normally: the type of `type` must be a class type that is publicly derived from the type of `e`...
- What do you think? Am I correct and this is a mistake in the book?

Thank you.

Comment: The wording is odd.  (But then again, getting exact wording for standard-ish things is already stilted.)  I presume the author meant the *actual* type of the object that the pointer or reference refers, rather than the type of the pointer or the type of the reference (presumably to a base class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the contrary he meant because if the type of e is derived from the type cast then we don't need a conversion or cast because they are implicitly convertible by inheritance

If the type isn't the same, then there must be a conversion in order to arrive to the target type, whether that conversion is implicit or explicit.

While it's true that we won't need a cast, that doesn't mean that the cast would fail. So no, I don't think they meant the contrary.
Upcasts succeed with dynamic cast, the quoted text is correct about that.

> But normally: the type of type must be a class type that is publicly derived from the type of e...

That's what the second condition means in the book:

> > In all cases, the type of e must be either a ..., **a public base class of the target type** , or ...

Comment: Ok Thanks. So It doesn't matter the type so at the end the case either succeeds or fails.

Comment: So you that means we can cast an object of derived class to a base class type which is not needed as long as they are types related by inheritance and implicitly convertible. right?

Comment: @Maestro Yes, we can do that.